# How to replace escaped newline in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a csv, that is not quoted, have added an example below

New lines are escaped with \, as shown in the 2nd row, is there a way to replace that with some other character using apache spark..

**Input CSV**

```
Banana,23,Male,5,11,2017
Cat,32,Fe\
male,2,11,2017
Dragon,28,Male,1,11,2017
```

**Expected Output**

```
Banana,23,Male,5,11,2017
Cat,32,Fe-male,2,11,2017
Dragon,28,Male,1,11,2017
```

**Note:** the original file is huge (around 40GB)

**Edit 1**
I just found an answer to use "sc. wholeTextFiles" instead of "sc.textFile", but given the big size I m not sure if it is memory efficient, please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and playing around this is what i came to

as @vikrant-rana suggested in the answer, 
reading with sc.textFile() and doing a map on the partitions is one way to try, but as the row we need to merge may go to different partition, this is not a reliable solution.. 
This may work sometimes when they fall on same partition, but will not work always

we can alternatively to use sc.wholeTextFiles() to read the file into single partition and do map over it, but that would read the whole file at once into the memory and is not suitable for huge files

Answer (score 1):

Here you go!

Python function:

```
def my_func(lista):
    new="\n".join(lista).replace("\\\n", "-").splitlines()
    return new
```

Call this function for your rdd partitions:

```
>>> newrdd = sc.textFile(PATH_TO_FILE).mapPartitions(my_func).map(lambda line : line.split(","))
>>> newrdd.take(5);
[[u'Banana', u'23', u'Male', u'5', u'11', u'2017'], [u'Cat', u'32', u'Fe-male', u'2', u'11', u'2017'], [u'Dragon', u'28', u'Male', u'1', u'11', u'2017']]
```

## now loading this input file to the dataframe:

```
newdf  = sc.textFile(PATH_TO_FILE).mapPartitions(my_func).map(lambda line : line.split(",")).toDF(['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5','Col5'])

>>> newdf.show();
+------+----+-------+----+----+----+
|  Col1|Col2|   Col3|Col4|Col5|Col5|
+------+----+-------+----+----+----+
|Banana|  23|   Male|   5|  11|2017|
|   Cat|  32|Fe-male|   2|  11|2017|
|Dragon|  28|   Male|   1|  11|2017|
+------+----+-------+----+----+----+
```

I guess you are expecting solution similar to this. Let me know if you were looking something else. I can tweak my function as per the requirements :-)

Comment: hey, i should have closed the ticket long back seem to have forgotten,

There is no valid solution to this using textFile, see my answer below

Comment: @Geethanadh.. did you checked my second answer stated above?? It's working fine.

Comment: check the answer i just posted, it will not work always

Comment: Hmmm. You seems have tested it on your big file.. anyway.. I just tried it using some function. Might not be a feasible solution.. Thanks.. I am just wondering that even if the row goes to other partition.. how it will affect the merge process

Comment: its because the merge works on the partition, if i want to merge the rows 2, 3 (Cat  rows), and they are in different partitions, they won't merge

try it yourself

rdd = sc.textFile('temp.txt', minPartitions=3).mapPartitions(my_func)
rdd.collect()